# How do I use "make" to build the mod_wsgi module package?

Tags: django, apache, command-line, makefile, mod-wsgi

> Once the package has been configured, it can be built by running: make

I ran the configure script and it said "process complete."

How do I perform this task in the terminal? I'm using a Mac. I'm not familiar with the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be in the directory where you ran `configure` (it should contain a `Makefile`) and just type `make` and hit enter.

Comment: I just tried and got this response: "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop." and I don't see any make files inside the folder.

Comment: Then you haven't run 'configure' first as the README with the source code tells you to do. Running of the 'configure' script will generate the Makefile required to build the code.

Comment: Here is the original terminal output: checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... /usr/sbin/apxs
checking Apache version... 2.2.22
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: error: cannot find input file: Makefile.in
logout

[Process completed] I put back the missing files it generated and ran configure again it worked. It put the make file in my home folder again for some reason. Moved it into the folder and tried make. looks like a success.